# Citing an acronym citation in text

Tags: citing

I would like to cite the SROCC in text. I would like for the citation in text to be (SROCC, 2019) AND that the corresponding reference starts with SROCC, for the sake of consistency and clarity.
The script is like so

```
@article{SROCC2019,
author = {Oppenheimer, M. and Glavovic, B.C. and Hinkel, J. and van de Wal, R. and Magnan, A.K. and Abd-Elgawad, A. and Cai, R. and Cifuentes-Jara, M. and DeConto, R.M. and Ghosh, T. and Hay, J. and Isla, F. and Marzeion, B. and Meyssignac, B. and Sebesvari, Z.},
journal = {IPCC Special Report on the Ocean and Cryosphere in a Changing Climate, SROCC},
mendeley-groups = {Thesis/SLR prediction,Thesis/SLR prediction/IPCC},
pages = {321--445},
title = {{Chapter 4: Sea Level Rise and Implications for Low-Lying Islands, Coasts and Communities}},
year = {2019}
}
```

In text, `\cite{SROCC2019}` gives "(Oppenheimer et al. (2019))". What can I use to have "(SROCC, 2019)" in text, that will equally add SROCC at the start of the reference?

> SROCC (2019). Oppenheimer, M., Glavovic, B., Hinkel, J., van de Wal, R., Magnan, A., Abd-Elgawad, A., Cai, R., Cifuentes-Jara, M., DeConto, R., Ghosh, T., Hay, J., Isla, F., Marzeion, B., Meyssignac, B., and Sebesvari, Z. Chapter 4: Sea Level Rise and Implications for Low-Lying Islands, Coasts and Communities. IPCC Special Report on the Ocean and Cryosphere in a Changing Climate, SROCC, pages 321–445.

I tried

```
\defcitealias{SROCC2019}{SROCC, 2019}
```

which works for the citation in text but the reference remains

> Oppenheimer, M., Glavovic, B., Hinkel, J., van de Wal, R., Magnan, A., Abd-Elgawad, A., Cai, R., Cifuentes-Jara, M., DeConto, R., Ghosh, T., Hay, J., Isla, F., Marzeion, B., Meyssignac, B., and Sebesvari, Z. (2019). Chapter 4: Sea Level Rise and Implications for Low-Lying Islands, Coasts and Communities. IPCC Special Report on the Ocean and Cryosphere in a Changing Climate, SROCC, pages 321–445.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927) that is compilable, contains the packages and the Bib(La)TeX set up you use and produces the output in question.

Comment: Assuming the bibliographic entries are sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames, should the entry be listed under `O` for `Oppenheimer` or under `S` for `SROCC`?